# Network Error when trying to register with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, credentials, mern

I have a register form with only one field (username).
When I try to register a new member I got that error 
`Error: Network Error`

Here is my Register Class

```
    constructor(props) {...}

    handleChange(event) {...}

    handleSubmit(event) {

        const username = this.state.username;
        console.log(username);

        axios.post("http://localhost:1270/", { username }, { withCredentials: true } 
            ).then(reponse => {
                console.log('register', reponse)
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {...}
```

And the my `server.js`

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

app.post('/', (request, reponse) => {
    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var dbo = db.db("mern-pool");
        var username = request.body.username;
        console.log(username);
        var obj = { 
            username:username
        };
        dbo.collection("students").insertOne(obj, function(err, result) {
            db.close();
            reponse.send('inserted');
        });
    });
});
```

If I delete this part of my code, my username is inserted correctly

```
 { withCredentials: true }
```

Comment: Are you making this request at the same domain? It's strange, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: @JmLavoier It's on two different server (one for React and one for nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

When `axios` requests don't return 200 it throw an error. You have to haddle it. Replace the axios call to this:

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:1270/", { username }, { withCredentials: true })
  .then(reponse => {
    console.log('register', reponse);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Axios Err', err);
  })
```

Then tell us.

This may caused by CORS... I already tried to set manualy the headers for CORS but still having issues, then I just `npm install cors` then:

```js
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: I get this error `Axios Err Error: "Network Error"
    createError createError.js:16
    handleError xhr.js:83` as well as two warnings `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:1270/’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).` and `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:1270/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: Remove this Headers you put in and `npm install cors`, `var cors = require('cors'); 
 app.use(cors())`. You are using `express` right?

Comment: Yes I'm using express, I still get the same errors when doing that

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on Jackson's answer, it looks like you have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` enabled as well as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`. CORS doesn't allow for * and credentials to be true, you have to specify `http://localhost:1270/` as an allowed origin in your api, that will allow you to have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true`.

CORS can be a pain if you don't know its quirks, it basically stops requests being made to the api from a location it doesn't recognize. So when you specify `*` that says it will allow every origin, every source, to be able to access the api. However, one quirk of CORS is that if your Allow-Origin is *, it will not allow `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true`. So if you need that to be true, you need to specify your client app origin (`http://localhost:1270/` I think) as an acceptable location to receive requests from.

Hope that makes sense and helps

Comment: I changed `*` for `http://localhost:1270/` and still get one error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:1270/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:1270/’).`

Comment: Is 1270 the route of your react app? On your api you need to set the react apps location as the allowed origin

Comment: Oh okay, my route to React is `localhost:3000` so I changed it but still the same error

Comment: Hmm that should do it. It's explicitly set to `http://localhost:3000`? Everything about the error points to that being the problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSAllowOriginNotMatchingOrigin